# Issue with webview

Tags: android

In my application i use a mix of html and native. In my web view i load a html page which has a which has an image in it. On click of the image i call a java script function which in turn calls the native code. My html tag is as below:

```
<img onclick=nextLevel('0'); id="d2">
```

My javascript method is as below:

```
function nextLevel(index)
```

`{
       Android.displayNextLevel(index);
    }`

Within the displayNextLevel method i start the next activity. The issue is when i click on the image on the html page multiple times the event gets triggered multiple times and the activity opens up multiple times. Am i missing out on something? How do i overcome this issue? Kindly help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could fiddle around in the html/js to make sure you can only click it once every now and then.

You could also ditch your function and instead use the [JavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) so you can handle stuff in your Java code instead.